# How to authenticate for FCM Rest API using Google REST API in PHP REST API?

Tags: php, firebase, api, rest, google-cloud-platform

I need to send a notification using FCM REST API. However, I am unable to authenticaate using an API key at the moment. The below is the API to hit.

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/proj-name/messages:send?key=XXX
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

The backend is in PHP so there isn't any supported package for it. Hence, I am trying to use it for sending the notification. The above API seem to take oauth 2 access token or login cookie or some auther vaidation method. However, I need to send it from my own REST API. How can I authenticate from PHP to the above API and send the notificaiton properly?

UPDATE::

LINK: [Authenticate using Service Account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#linux-or-macos)

This API documents on how to authenticate using service accounts. Especially the below lines says the following:

> **Use credentials to mint access tokens**
> Unless you are using the Admin SDK, which handle authorization automatically, you'll need to mint the access token and add it to send requests.
>
> Use your Firebase credentials together with the Google Auth Library for your preferred language to retrieve a short-lived OAuth 2.0 access token:

But it does not provide/document any method for minting the short lived access token.

Comment: What indicate the API documentation ? With Oauth2, the token is generaly sent in the header Authorization: Bearer access_token

Comment: I am looking for the API from which I can get the Oauth2 ID token. I need the ID token but the ID token where do I receive it?

Comment: I'm confusing oauth2 and openId Connect. I don't remember if oauth2 give an id_token. But OIDC give id_token and access_token at the same time with the endpoint token. But id_token contains some user informations in it (it's a JWT). Access_token can give you theses informations with the endpoint userinfo

Comment: I would recommend you have a look at these:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174288/getting-firebase-bearer-token-by-simple-httpcall-postman
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399170/what-bearer-token-should-i-be-using-for-firebase-cloud-messaging-testing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74341945/oauth2-access-token-via-rest-http